# Aggregating data based on conditionals

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks something like this...

```
pd.DataFrame({
 'car_id': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1','1','1','1'],
 'odometer_start': [0, 3, 6, 9, 13, 18, 39, 89, 101, 107, 122, 182],
 'odometer_end': [3, 6, 9, 13, 18, 39, 89, 101, 107, 122, 182, 206],
 'need_maintanince': [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
 })
```

and I essentially want to aggregate the difference in the odometer for each observation since the last time a triggered a need for maintenance (=1).

so I expect it to come out like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({
 'car_id': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1','1','1','1'],
 'odometer_start': [0, 3, 6, 9, 13, 18, 39, 89, 101, 107, 122, 182],
 'odometer_end': [3, 6, 9, 13, 18, 39, 89, 101, 107, 122, 182, 206],
 'need_maintanince': [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
 'miles_since_maint': [0,0,0,4,9,30,80,12,18,15,75,24]})
```

Basically, it would look at each observation and do a cumulative sum on how many miles it has been since an observation of the same car_id has been marked as needing a repair. Then it will continue to cumulatively sum the miles since that maintenance.

For reference, I am trying to predict the number of miles before a car is needed to be repaired.

Anyone know how this can be done?

EDIT:

I don't think I made the expected output as clear as I should of. Updated it to match what I need and made the dataframe a little simpler to interpret, since multiple car id's were confusing even me.

Comment: Do you rather mean: `'miles_since_last_maint': [0,0,0,0,2,0,11,33,0,0,42,0,12]`

Comment: @dallonsi yes, thank you. I was writing this post from a phone and was in quite a hurry hahaha.

Comment: let me edit your post properly ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to give the result you are looking for:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'car_id': ['1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '1','2','2','4','4'],
 'odometer_start': [0, 5, 9, 1,3, 8,19,52,11,22,64,132, 144],
 'need_maintanince': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
 })

df['miles_since_maint'] = (df.groupby('car_id')['odometer_start'].diff() 
                            * df['need_maintanince']).fillna(0)
```

```
   car_id        ...          miles_since_maint
0       1        ...                        0.0
1       2        ...                        0.0
2       2        ...                        0.0
3       3        ...                        0.0
4       3        ...                        2.0
5       3        ...                        0.0
6       3        ...                       11.0
7       3        ...                       33.0
8       1        ...                        0.0
9       2        ...                        0.0
10      2        ...                       42.0
11      4        ...                        0.0
12      4        ...                       12.0
```

---

Edit per comment:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'car_id': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1','1','1','1'],
 'odometer_start': [0, 3, 6, 9, 13, 18, 39, 89, 101, 107, 122, 182],
 'odometer_end': [3, 6, 9, 13, 18, 39, 89, 101, 107, 122, 182, 206],
 'need_maintanince': [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
 'miles_since_maint': [0,0,0,4,9,30,80,12,18,15,75,24]})

df['odo_chg'] = df['odometer_end'] - df['odometer_start']
maint_group = df['need_maintanince'].shift().cumsum().fillna(0)
df['miles_since_maint_2'] = (df.groupby(['car_id', maint_group])['odo_chg'].cumsum())
# Reassign initial group to 0 per desired output
df.loc[maint_group == 0, 'miles_since_maint_2'] = 0
df.T
```

gives (transposed for easier viewing)

```
                    0  1  2   3   4   5   6    7    8    9    10   11
car_id               1  1  1   1   1   1   1    1    1    1    1    1
odometer_start       0  3  6   9  13  18  39   89  101  107  122  182
odometer_end         3  6  9  13  18  39  89  101  107  122  182  206
need_maintanince     0  0  1   0   0   0   1    0    1    0    1    0
miles_since_maint    0  0  0   4   9  30  80   12   18   15   75   24
odo_chg              3  3  3   4   5  21  50   12    6   15   60   24
miles_since_maint_2  0  0  0   4   9  30  80   12   18   15   75   24
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to help me. Unfortunately, I am stupid and didn't do a good job of explaining what I was expecting. I updated the post. Essentially I want a cumulative sum on the odometer_end between each observation marked as in need of a repair. Have any thoughts on this?

Comment: @KyleMcComb That makes more sense (was wondering about that, actually). See edit.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
s = df.groupby('car_id')['odometer_start'].diff()
df['miles_since_last_maint'] = np.where(df['need_maintanince'], s, 0)
```

gives

```
   car_id  odometer_start  need_maintanince  miles_since_last_maint
0       1               0                 0                     0.0
1       2               5                 0                     0.0
2       2               9                 0                     0.0
3       3               1                 0                     0.0
4       3               3                 1                     2.0
5       3               8                 0                     0.0
6       3              19                 1                    11.0
7       3              52                 1                    33.0
8       1              11                 0                     0.0
9       2              22                 0                     0.0
10      2              64                 1                    42.0
11      4             132                 0                     0.0
12      4             144                 1                    12.0
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to help me. Unfortunately, I am stupid and didn't do a good job of explaining what I was expecting. I updated the post. Essentially I want a cumulative sum on the odometer_end between each observation marked as in need of a repair. Have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Quang Hoang's answer but as one-liner without numpy:

```
df['miles_since_last_maint'] = df.groupby('car_id')['odometer_start'].diff().where(df.need_maintanince==1,0).astype(int)
```

Result:

```
   car_id  need_maintanince  odometer_start  miles_since_last_maint
0       1                 0               0                       0
1       2                 0               5                       0
2       2                 0               9                       0
3       3                 0               1                       0
4       3                 1               3                       2
5       3                 0               8                       0
6       3                 1              19                      11
7       3                 1              52                      33
8       1                 0              11                       0
9       2                 0              22                       0
10      2                 1              64                      42
11      4                 0             132                       0
12      4                 1             144                      12
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to help me. Unfortunately, I am stupid and didn't do a good job of explaining what I was expecting. I updated the post. Essentially I want a cumulative sum on the odometer_end between each observation marked as in need of a repair. Have any thoughts on this?